# How does Karma theory explain premature deliveries and the death of infants?

Tags: karma, parents, children

Sometimes, infants are born prematurely and die shortly thereafter.  Is it possible to explain such tragedies using the karma theory?

Has it got to do with the karma of the parents or the infant child or both?

Comment: It's because of both karmas. It's your karma to give a birth to a premature baby. And it's also baby's karma to be born prematurely and pass away soon.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar "Do infants die because of their own karma or of parents ? " Both

Comment: Yes it is possible. The 7 of the 8 vasus (one of whom was Bhishma) had to take birth because of their karma. However, their karma was limited to just having to take birth and not to the extent of suffering through human samsara. So they were released from their karma (i.e. birth) immediately by way of losing their lives as babies.

Answer (score 2):

According to the karma theory, there is no such thing as tragedy or miracle in the first place. Each one reaps what he sows. He has no choice but to reap. It is felt that a particular event is favourable or otherwise, only because we do not have the memory our actions in many earlier births that led to the event. If we do, we would not be in a position to react. From the individual point of view, feelings may be attached to an event. But from the viewpoint of eternal justice, events unfold as preordained.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE. We appreciate your active participation in answering questions on this Q?A forum. But while answering questions on this site its' necessary to provide sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Bhagavad Gita , Puranas , Upanishads etc. And this rule is mandatory. Pure personal opinions and wikipedia / blog sources generally are not encouraged in answers here .Please do provide some sources in your answers from now on. Otherwise its possible that some of your answers will receive flags and will get deleted from site. Also register on this site as a regular user